# How to have inherited type hints in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.5, type-hinting, mypy

So my problem is That when I have a class of type `A` that does things and I use those functions as a `subclass(B)` they are still typed for class `A` and do not accept my class `B` object as arguments or as function signature.

My problem simplified:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable

T = TypeVar('T')


class Signal(Generic[T]):
    def connect(self, connector: Callable[[T], None]) -> None:
        pass

    def emit(self, payload: T):
        pass


class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.signal = Signal[A]()

    def do(self) -> None:
        self.signal.emit(self)

def handle_b(b: "B") -> None:
    print(b.something)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.signal.connect(handle_b)

    @property
    def something(self) -> int:
        return 42
```

I can provide the complete signal class as well but that just distracts from the problem. This leaves me with one error in mypy:

> ```
> error: Argument 1 to "connect" of "Signal" has incompatible type Callable[[B], None]; expected Callable[[A], None]
> ```

Since the signal handling is implemented in `A` the subclass `B` can't expect `B` type objects to be returned even though it clearly should be fine...

Comment: Well, the error is correct, you did constrain `self.signal` to `A` only: `self.signal = Signal[A]()`.

Comment: You basically set `T = A` there. `B` may be a subclass, but because `A.something` doesn't exist, you can't use that attribute. You tied everything down to `A` now. A method that accepts `B` is obviously allowed to use `B.something` so the base class `A` can't ever satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The `connector` passed to `Signal[A]` is of type `Callable[[A], None]`, which means it has to promise to be able to handle any instance of `A` (or any of it's sub-classes). `handle_b` cannot fulfill this promise, since it only works for instances of `B`, it therefore cannot be used as a `connector` for a `signal` of type `Signal[A]`.

Presumably, the `connector` of the `signal` of any instance of `B` will only ever be asked to handle an instance of `B`, it therefore doesn't need to be of type `Signal[A]`, but `Signal[B]` would be sufficient. This means the type of `signal` is not fixed, but varies for different sub-classes of `A`, this means `A` needs to be generic.

[The answer by ogurets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251337/1695064) correctly makes `A` generic, however there is no a problem with `do`, since it's unclear whether `self` is of type expected by `self.signal.emit`. We can promise that these types will always match by annotating `self` with the same type variable used for `Signal`. By using a new type variable `_A` which is bound by `A`, we tell mypy that `self` will always be a subtype of `A` and therefore has a property `signal`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')


class Signal(Generic[T]):
    def connect(self, connector: Callable[[T], None]) -> None:
        pass

    def emit(self, payload: T):
        print(payload)

_A = TypeVar('_A', bound='A')

class A(Generic[_A]):
    signal: Signal[_A]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.signal = Signal[_A]()

    def do(self) -> None:
        self.signal.emit(self)

def handle_b(b: "B") -> None:
    print(b.something)

class B(A['B']):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.signal.connect(handle_b)

    @property
    def something(self) -> int:
        return 42

b = B()
reveal_type(b.signal) # Revealed type is '...Signal[...B*]'
```

Answer (score 0):

The type hint error is entirely correct. You created a `Signal` instance with `A` as the type, in the `__init__` method of `A`:

```
self.signal = Signal[A]()
```

Passing in a subclass is fine, but all code interacting with that `Signal` instance now *has* to work for `A` instances only. `handle_b()` on the other handrequires an instance of `B`, and can't lower the requirement to `A` instead.

Drop the constraint:

```
self.signal = Signal()
```

or create an instance in each subclass with the correct type.

Comment: shouldn't there be a way to tell the type Hinting to accept subtypes of A?
I mean disabling the typing works, but then why have type hinting at all...

Comment: Sorry, had to step away from the keyboard for a while; it probably is possible to use a `TypeVar()` marked as covariant instead of `A` but won’t be able to test until tomorrow.

Comment: I did already try that, I get a problem.py:10: error: Cannot use a covariant type variable as a parameter
on the line: def emit(self, payload: T):
And still have the old error :D maybe upgrade my mypy version...

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable

T = TypeVar('T')


class Signal(Generic[T]):
    def connect(self, connector: Callable[[T], None]) -> None:
        pass

    def emit(self, payload: T):
        pass


class A(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.signal = Signal[T]()

    def do(self: A) -> None:
        self.signal.emit(self)


def handle_b(b: B) -> None:
    print(b.something)


class C:
    pass


def handle_c(c: C) -> None:
    print(c)


class B(A[B]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.signal.connect(handle_b)  # OK
        self.signal.connect(handle_c)  # incompatible type

    @property
    def something(self) -> int:
        return 42
```

Comment: nice idea, but I still have errors on the emit of class A and the emit function definition itself, with mypy 0.600

Comment: Hmm.. Last version of pip's mypy (0.5.0) looks fine. Sadly, too busy to dive deeper into this for now.